# Python/Django Проблема с созданием проекта

Tags: python, django

Установил `Django` и хочу создать там новый проект.
Выбрал папку командой `cd` и пишу:

```sh
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Ответ:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in run_module_as_main
return run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\danii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\django-admin.exe_main.py", line 4, in
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init.py", line 12, in
from django.conf import settings
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf_init.py", line 19, in
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py", line 8, in
from django.utils.encoding import punycode
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 8, in
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 1, in
import asyncio
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio_init.py", line 8, in
from .base_events import *
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 40, in
from . import events
File "c:\users\danii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 783, in
from _asyncio import (_get_running_loop, set_running_loop,
AttributeError: module 'traceback' has no attribute 'extract_stack'
```

Версии:

- Python 3.9
- Django 3.1.3

Я недавно начал этим заниматься, поэтому ошибка может быть очень глупой

Comment: У вас python 3.8, судя по путям в ошибке :) Странная ошибка, ведь `traceback` это модуль из коробки и тот метод тоже в него входит. Нет ли у вас в папке проекта файла с таким названием? И если открыть `asyncio\events.py` в строке 783 что находится?

Comment: Предыдущий комментатор, кмк, прав. У вас бардак в интерпритаторах, судя по всему. Могу только посоветовать изучить вопрос о виртуальных окружениях (venv, virtualenv) и под каждый проект создавать собственное окружение. Чаще всего это избавляет от подобных проблем

Comment: Спасибо, сработало